# Best way for an Iphone app to talk to a Java server through a full-duplex connection (chat or game)

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

My client is in an Iphone app (game with chat) and it will be talking to a Java server. What is the best way (protocol / interface) for my Iphone app to talk to my server? I know you can use HTTP, but it is a request / response protocol. I could always request something and wait for asynchronous notifications from server. Then request again, implementing something like a [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) server.

Anyways, what is the industry standard for this type of communication: Iphone app talking to Java server, supporting asynchronous "push" notifications from server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'standard'. It's more of a do what fits your application. Look at your requirements, and think of ways to solve it. Then look for existing solutions if they exist.

Comment: Those are two separate protocols. Typical games don't need full duplex communication; unicast streams typically tend to be all that's required. However, for chat, you're going to want something with error correction, and since your realtime requirements aren't as high as with the game data, using something like XMPP could be beneficial.

Comment: Btw, to the downvoter, if you don't like what I suggested, please leave a comment explaining why.